Help - Is it possible to somehow authorise a paid for Armadillo protected abandoned program?
I hope this is permitted.
Back story: As a video professional I paid for many expensive licenses years ago for some specific Video encoding software. Sadly, the company abandoned the software and in fact later made it open source and also had a free version for the public. In my humble opinion the original 'paid for' version had distinct advantages over the free version. The workflow was better and I perceive it was more stable.
In any case I believe the paid for version was protected by Armadillo software which is now also abandoned. So I have a dilemma here. I invested a lot of money on licenses - thousands of dollars and I have only one last computer that is licensed and that will die eventually but I still love the software.
With no way to authorize any new computers going forward is there a legit way to authorise this software? Original software division of the company is now defunct.
I hope that some clever people may help me in my trouble. Happy to offer something for anyone's time as well if successful.
Many thanks for any responses

try cloning the computer
